# Comparing two files by the content in their lines in Scala

Tags: scala, file, comparison, file-comparison, filecompare

I have two files in `.dimacs` format, eg:

```
 c example_01.cnf
 p cnf 6 9
  1 0
 -2 1 0
 -1 2 0
 -5 1 0
 -6 1 0
 -3 2 0
 -4 2 0
 -3 -4 0
  3 4 -2 0
```

and,

```
c example_02.cnf
p cnf 9 6
-7 2 0
7 -2 0
-8 3 0
8 -3 0
-9 4 0
9 -4 0
```

I want to compare file `example_01.cnf` with `example_02.cnf` such that, to extract ***only*** those lines from file `example_01.cnf` that have a similar value (in any of the lines) from file `example_02.cnf`, and to save the result in a new file e.g., `example_result.cnf`.

In this case, the `example_result.cnf` will look like:

```
c example_result.cnf
p cnf 4 6
-2 1 0
-1 2 0 
-3 2 0
-4 2 0
-3 -4 0
3 4 -2 0
```

Eg., the lines `1 0`, `-5 1 0` and `-6 1 0` are not in the resulting file because none of the numbers `1`, `5`, and `6` are in the `example_02.cnf`.

My current code is:

```
import scala.io.Source

    object Example_01 {

      val source = Source.fromFile("example_01.cnf")
      val source2 = Source.fromFile("example_02.cnf")
      val destination = new PrintWriter(new File("example_result.cnf"))

      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        var nrVariables: Int = 0
        var nrLines: Int = 0

        destination.write("c example_result.cnf \n")
        destination.write("p cnf " + nrVariables + " " + nrLines + "\n") //not finished!

        /* How I can compare the all the numbers from the second file 'source2' like in the 'if' statement below? */            
         for(line <- source.getLines()) ; if line.contains("2") & line.contains("0") ) {
            destination.write(line)
            destination.write("\n")
            nrLines += 1        
        }
        source.close()
        destination.close()
      }
```

In this code I am not using the second file `example_02.cnf` yet. How I can compare these two files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to save lines form source1 that contains a number in any line of source2 this should work:

```
object Example {
  val source = Source.fromFile("example_01.cnf").getLines()
  val source2 = Source.fromFile("example_02.cnf").getLines()
  val nrsSource2 = source2.mkString(" ").split(" ").distinct.diff(Array("0"))

  val linesToSave = source.drop(2).filter {
    l =>
      l.split(" ").exists(nr => nrsSource2.contains(nr))
  }

  val nrLines = linesToSave.length
  val nrVariables = ??? //don't know what this is

  //write linesToSave to a file
}
```

Not sure about what the nrVariables represents, but it should be easy to calculate from the `linesToSave`.

Comment: I am trying with this filter method and I don't know why I am getting again the same file 1. It looks like `exists(nr => nrsSource2.contains(nr))` is becoming true always! :( Btw, I checked what `nrsSource2` is containing, and it looks everything fine on it. Do you have any clue, why?

Comment: @user4712458 I think it's forAll instead of exists. Check my updated answer

Comment: the method `forall()` seems to work with a problem: when a number from `nrSource2` is not found in `source`, then it's deleting / (not checking) in those lines anymore :/ It eliminates lines before checking for the other values from `nrSource2`.

Comment: @user4712458 Maybe I didn't understand the question, why is `1 0` not in the `example_result.cnf`? `0` appears in the source2 lines. Should I check only the first number of each line? or the first 2 numbers of each line?

Comment: I need to select only those lines in the first file `example_01.cnf` that contains at least one value/number from the second file `example_02.cnf`. So, sorry if I haven't explain it enough, but despite in which line and at what position in file `example_01.cnf`  a value from file `example_02.cnf` is, the _whole_ line should be selcted and saved in file `example_result.cnf`.

Comment: @user4712458 so why isn't the line 1 0 selected in your example? the number 0 exists in source2

Comment: hey thnx for this last question. It helped me to understand why the `exists` method "didn't function before" and why the `forall` isn't functioning either. The solution that I have is, after excluding the `0` value from `nrsSource2`, like `val nrsSource2 = traces.mkString(" ").split(" ").distinct diff Array("0")`, now I have the right results _but_ by using the method `exists`. So, if you have a little time, you can change your answer and I will accept your answer. Thnx million times!

Comment: @user4712458 nice! glad it worked. just edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually it should be smth like following:

```
val file1: List[String] = // read file and getLines
val file2: List[String] = // read file and getLines

val result = file1.filter { line => 
  file2.contains(line)
}
```